# How to change Prometheus.yml file in the container

Tags: docker, nginx, prometheus, docker-container

How can I change my / Prometheus/ Prometheus.yml on the container itself 
I want it to track
1) my appserver - an Node application in a docker container
2) my postgres  db
3) my apached and nginx web server

I do know that one has to change the Prometheus.yml file and add targets

Comment: general steps  step 1 map /prometheus  to host directory step 2 save prometheus.yml on the host directory which will be reflected in /prometheus directory step 3 use cp command to move from /prometheus to /etc/prometheus step 4 reload prometheus container and go to localhost:9090/targets if yml is well formed then you should see your targets

Comment: Hi @user17970, there's no problem answering your own question but in this case don't leave a comment, post a clear, understandable and well-formatted answer. Think about other people coming from Google with the same issue ! Also, it's up to you to accept one answer (accepting doesn't mean it's the best, it just means that it worked for the person who asked), or leave feedback. Good answers are voted up and rise to the top, useless/wrong ones are voted down and falls to the bottom. Users who consistently provide useful content accrue reputation and are granted more privileges (and conversely).

Comment: You might find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and more precisely by reading [How do I write a good answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why is voting important ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). You complained about the number of question of yours remaining unanswered - this one among others, while posting your own answer as a comment.. - so I hope you will understand the approach here because I'm very concerned about this kind of issue. We all know some days are slower than others. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Generic mechanisms to change docker images are

1. Mount your configuration file at the desired path.
2. Create a new image by copying the co fig file in the new Dockerfile. Not recommended if you have to use different configs for different environments/apps
3. Change the file on the running container if the application (peomerheus in  this case) supports it. I know that some of the apps like Kibana do this. Good for debugging, not recommended for production environments.

Comment: Prometheus does support live reload of configuration, so that helps with debugging. But, mounting the external file seems to be the best and easiest option, by far.

Comment: A SIGHUP signal will make prometheus reread its configuration file so: `docker kill --signal SIGHUP prom-container`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be precise with an answer given the lack of details but in general, you place your modified `prometheus.yml` file within the Docker context and modify your `Dockerfile` to add the instruction

```
COPY prometheus.yml /path/to/prometheus.yml
```

Comment: `COPY` is preferred over `ADD` unless you need the specific functionality that `ADD` provides: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy

Answer (score 0):

Open the docker container in interactive mode

```
docker exec -it <container__id> /bin/sh
```

Then change the *prometheus.yml* file which should be placed at
**/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml**

Now, Stop the container and restart the same container. So, now it will read the updated configuration file.